# Unable to load class for Custom Gradle plugin in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create a custom plugin which i can apply in the gradle.build file.  There are a few ways to do this but i am doing it using the buildSrc folder. This means the plugin will be tied to my build and not portable. 
from the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) the buildSrc folder should have the following properties:

> buildSrc project
>   You can put the source for the task class in the rootProjectDir/buildSrc/src/main/groovy directory. Gradle will take care of compiling and testing the task class and making it available on the classpath of the build script. The task class is visible to every build script used by the build. However, it is not visible outside the build, and so you cannot reuse the task class outside the build it is defined in. Using the buildSrc project approach separates the task declaration - that is, what the task should do - from the task implementation - that is, how the task does it.

But anyway my issue is below:

already i created a buildSrc directory in the root project path and created a groovy folder which is recognized by the IDE.

below is my fold structure and the error i am getting:

[image]

Now here is the task and the plugin itself:

RenameAppVersionNameTask.groovy:

```
    package com.myplugins
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

class RenameAppVersionNameTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def run() {
        project.configure(project) {
            // Check if plugin works on an Android module
            if (it.hasProperty("android")) {
                // Iterate over app build variants (build types + flavors)
                project.android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                    // Only change debug build type variants
                    if (variant.buildType.name == project.android.buildTypes.debug.name) {
                        // Rename versionName
                        def customVersionName = variant.mergedFlavor.versionName
                        variant.mergedFlavor.versionName = customVersionName + " custom"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    RenameAppVersionNameTask() {
        group = 'customPlugin'
        description = 'Renames versionName of the app depends on the current git branch name'

    }
}
```

CustomPlugin.groovy:

```
    package com.myplugins
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('renameAppVersionName', type: RenameAppVersionNameTask)
        project.tasks.getByName('preBuild').dependsOn('renameAppVersionName')
    }

}
```

The error i am receiving on gradle sync is:

```
Failed to sync Gradle project 'My GradlePluginApplication'
Error:Unable to load class 'CustomPlugin'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

also i noticed i cant even apply the plugin:

[image]

I confirmed android studio is using the gradle wrapper. 
also if needed the gradle-wrapper.properties is below:

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `build.gradle` file that lives inside of the `buildSrc` directory. This will tell the `buildSrc` project what plugins to use and what dependencies to pull in.

It would look something similar to this

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile localGroovy()
  compile gradleApi()
}
```

and would live in the root of the `buildSrc`

I also am not sure you need to create a custom plugin, and could instead use your task in your project's gradle file.

Comment: i am following a demo. thats why i built it this way. clearly it can be done with just a single task.  I didn't realizse i needed a build.gradle file. that resolved my issue. thanks.

Comment: in my case, i lost "jcenter()" repository, only had "mavenCentral", thx to remand me adding jcenter.(Of course this's in build.gradle inside buildSrc directory)